# Bridged Networking with bhyve and FreeBSD Guests does not work

Tags: virtual-machines, freebsd, bridge

I have a FreeBSD10 host with bhyve and the following IP-configuration in rc.conf:

```
ifconfig_igb0="inet X.X.X.146 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast X.X.X.255"
defaultrouter="X.X.X.254"
cloned_interfaces="bridge0"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm igb0 up"
```

The tap device gets added via the vmrc scripts.
I have another IPv4 Address from my hoster which is in *another subnet*: `Y.Y.Y.176`.
The hoster gives me the following guide to configure bridged-networking with this IP: [Bridged Networking](http://help.ovh.co.uk/BridgeClient#link5)

According to this guide I configured the guest (FreeBSD10) like this (the hoster provides me with a "virtual MAC" for the IP):

```
ifconfig_vtnet0="inet Y.Y.Y.176 netmask 255.255.255.255 ether 02:00:00:8c:46:32"
static_routes="net1 net2"
route_net1="-net X.X.X.254/32 Y.Y.Y.176"
route_net2="default X.X.X.254"
```

Before starting the VM I setup the bridge like this:

```
ifconfig bridge0 addm igb0 addm tap0 up
```

with `tap0`being the "host-side" of the VMs network adapter.

This does not work. I can't reach the gateway from within the VM and I can't reach the host from the VM. This makes sense to me, because there are no routes. It's unclear how this could even work.

Comment: Please avoid [using other people's public IP addresses](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) in your examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not solve, but rather circumvent the problem:

I assigned `igb0` on the host all the IPs with a `/32` network-mask, instead of the VMs and assigned bridge0 the private IP `10.0.0.1/24`, the `vtnet0` interface in the VM gets assigned `10.0.0.2` with a default-gateway of `10.0.0.1` and I create a binat using pf.

The `rc.conf` on the host looks like this:

```
ifconfig_igb0="inet X.X.X.146 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast X.X.X.255"
defaultrouter="X.X.X.254"

ifconfig_igb0_alias0="inet Y.Y.Y.176/32"
ifconfig_igb0_alias1="inet Y.Y.Y.177/32"
ifconfig_igb0_alias2="inet Y.Y.Y.178/32"
ifconfig_igb0_alias3="inet Y.Y.Y.179/32"

cloned_interfaces="bridge0"
ifconfig_bridge0="inet 10.0.0.1/24"
```

And the `pf.conf` on the host:

```
vm_if1 = "Y.Y.Y.176"
vm_if2 = "Y.Y.Y.177"
vm_if3 = "Y.Y.Y.178"
vm_if4 = "Y.Y.Y.179"

slave = "10.0.0.4"

binat on igb0 from $slave to any -> $vm_if1
nat on igb0 from bridge0:network to any -> (igb0)
```

The VMs `rc.conf` is really easy:

```
ifconfig_vtnet0="10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="10.0.0.1"
```

Now, whenever I provision a new VM, it needs a IP within the `10.0.0.0/24` range and I need to adjust the hosts `pf.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

You likely need to do:

```
ifconfig tap0 up
```

and/or add `net.link.tap.up_on_open=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it auto-up.

Normally, the tap interface doesn't come up until you give it an IP.

This should make the bridge work.

To configure the bridge in `rc.conf`:

```
cloned_interfaces="bridge0 tap0"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm igb0 addm tap0 up"
```

You also need:

```
if_bridge_load="YES"
if_tap_load="YES"
```

in `/boot/loader.conf` so that tap can be created on the fly.

See the official instructions I wrote [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/virtualization-host-bhyve.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it specifically - the bridge gets of course configured like you said. Question updated. Regarding the sysctl and the modules - I did that too. I followed the exact guide you're mentioning. If I route the subnet the "normal" way, I can get it to work - just the "use all IPs as host-addresses"-thing seems to make problems.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the question is more than half a year old, since I just had the same problem

Don't configure your IP address on the physical member interfaces of the bridge but the bridge interface itself. This is mentioned in the [FreeBSD handbooks section on bridging](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/book.html#network-bridging).

My understanding is that this is due to the way the packets are processed. `if_bridge(4)` covers some of it in the section about filtering.